# How to show that for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ there is a unique $b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ab = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Here is the whole question:
Show that for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with $a \neq 0$, there exists a unique $b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ab = 1$.

I believe I have shown that it exists.

Proof:
Suppose $a \in \mathbb{C}$ where $a \neq 0$. Let $b = 1/a \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $ab = a(1/a) = a/a = 1$. Thus there exists a $b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that ab = 1.

I am confused on how to show that it is unique. Do I suppose that there exist a $b_1$ and $b_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ab_1 = 1$ and $ab_2 = 1$? If I do that, I have $ab_1 = ab_2 = 1$, then I can multiply on the left by the multiplicative inverse of $a$. That gives me $b_1 = b_2 = 1/a$. Is that okay? It seems kind of circular to me, since earlier I took $b = 1/a$.

Also, I found a solution online for showing uniqueness, but I don't understand the mechanics of how this is showing that it is unique:
If $ab = 1$, then
b = $1 \cdot b$ = $(\frac{1}{a} \cdot a) \cdot b = \frac{1}{a} \cdot (a \cdot b) = (\frac{1}{a} \cdot 1) = \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: What $b$ works for $a=0$?

Comment: Need to specify a $\ne$ 0.  How do you know that 1/a actually exists?  That's actually what you are being asked to prove.

Comment: @fleablood Oh sorry, I forgot to copy that the statement of the question requires that a is not zero. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: What axioms are you supposed to be using; that is, what do you know about $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @pjs36 It defines for $a \neq 0$ that $1/a$ is the unique complex number such that $a(1/a) = 1$. It also defines division on C: $b/a = b (1/a)$.

Comment: Well, I mean... If you are given that $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is a group, the standard group-theoretic proof that inverses are unique will work. Or if your axioms guarantee it's an integral domain, you have a different proof that inverses are unique. My point is that your proof depends on what you know/are allowed to use.

Comment: @pjs36 This is from the first section (1.A) of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. The only definitions so far in the text are addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$, subtraction, the multiplicative inverse, and division. The multiplicative inverse is defined to be unique.

Comment: $(a+ib)(a-ib) = a^2+b^2$, not too far of the inverse

Comment: @user1952009 I know that's true but I don't know what that has to do with the inverse?

Comment: if $a\ne 0$ or $b \ne 0$, $(a+ib)^{-1} = \frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}$ and the uniqueness is obvious

Comment: I've you have an axiom that the multiplicative inverse exists and is unique, then there is absolutely nothing to prove.  This statement *is* the axiom.

Comment: The solution is, by definition, identical to the multiplicative inverse.  There is absolutely nothing to prove.

Comment: Okay, the problem is to prove the inverse axiom.  So you can't assume 1/a is known.  You have to figure out what 1/a is.  And show it is the only solution.

Comment: @Lsonic Are you sure those axioms weren't given for $\mathbb{R}$ instead? As the other commenters note, the statement you are trying to prove in your question is true **if and only if** elements of $\mathbb{C}$ have multiplicative inverses. If that is one of your axioms, then you can't prove your statement because it is axiomatically true.

Comment: Or, rather, the proof is the very short "By axiom IV, done" or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to basic properties like this (we take existence and uniqueness of multiplicative inverse for granted, more often than not!) it really is important to be pedantic and dot every i. Otherwise, you might as well just say "Well, everyone knows that, of course it's true."

OK, so following Axler's text, all we know is that complex numbers look like $a + bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and they have the addition and multiplication that we all know. So, if you want to show that some nonzero $z = a + bi \in \Bbb C$ has an inverse, it really isn't good enough (in my opinion) to say that $1/z$ works. Does $1/z$ look like $a + bi$ for some real $a, b$? If you can't show how to put it in that form, then you don't know $1/z$ is indeed a complex number.

Now, suppose you've spelled out how to write $1/z$ in the $a + bi$ form (I do hope you remember how that works; use the conjugate of the denominator). Also, let's suppose that you've proven the other properties about $\Bbb C$ that we all know, namely

- multiplication and addition are commutative and associative (truly grueling to demonstrate) and that
- we have additive and multiplicative identities.

We'd like to show that that the multiplicative inverse of a fixed but arbitrary nonzero $z \in \Bbb C$ is unique.

The standard computation that you're likely to see in a text on group theory is the following. It relies on the existence of inverses, the existence of the (multiplicative) identity $1$, and associativity.

> Given $0 \neq z \in \Bbb C$, suppose $w_1$ and $w_2$ are both multiplicative inverses of $z$. Among other things, this means that $z w_2 = 1 = w_1 z$. Then we have
>
> $$w_1 = w_1 \cdot 1 = w_1(z w_2) = (w_1 z)w_2 = 1 \cdot w_2 = w_2,$$
>
> so that $w_1 = w_2$ and the inverse of $z$ is indeed unique, as desired.

Since we know so little about $\Bbb C$ from the axioms given, it's mostly just a trick and not terribly interesting -- but make sure you can say *exactly* what property is used at each step. The same kind of computation, replacing $\cdot$ with $+$, shows that additive inverses are unique too, assuming the corresponding properties of addition

Comment: OK I think I get what you're saying. So when I work out what real numbers $c, d$ satisfy $1/(a + bi) = c + di$, that shows the existence of the additive inverse. If you're familiar with Axler's book, what does he mean in definition 1.5 in chapter 1 (3rd edition) when he writes: "For $a \neq 0$, let $1/a$ denote the multiplicative inverse of $a$. Thus $1/a$ is the unique complex number such that $a(1/a) = 1$". Is that statement assuming that the multiplicative inverse actually exists? (So that's why I'm being asked to prove it?)

Comment: I didn't focus on existence, good question. Being pedantic, we should figure out *how* to write the inverse in $c + di$ form, *then* show that it is indeed the inverse by multiplying. The $a \neq 0$ section comes after he tells the reader to prove that multiplicative inverses exist and are unique -- so that part seems to be telling the reader, "I'm using the notation $1/z$ to mean the multiplicative inverse of $z$. You just proved existence and uniqueness of multiplicative inverses, so the thing $1/z$ is referring to exists and can mean only one thing."

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what's going on now. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful. What do you mean by $1/a$? It might sound like I'm being silly, because you *want* to say "of course I know what I mean by $1/a$; it's $1$ divided by $a$". But *what do you mean by dividing by $a$*? If I write down the symbols $$\frac{1}{1+i}$$
what does that mean? I'm claiming (well, you are) that it's a complex number. Well, if it's a complex number, what is its real part? What is its imaginary part? It's not clear.

Alright, now that's out of the way, let's find our $b$. We really hope that our usual properties for $\mathbb{R}$ hold, so we would hope that $$\frac{1}{1+i}=\frac{1-i}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)$$
Just to be clear, the first thing we wrote might not be a complex number, it's just a meaningless collection of symbols at the moment. But the last term is definitely a complex number! We absolutely know how to divide by real numbers like $2$, so we're fine. Now for the real test, is it really an inverse for $1+i$? Well, $$(1+i)\frac{1}{2}(1-i)=2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=1$$
Exactly as we hoped! In fact, for any complex number $a$ we have $$a\cdot \frac{\bar{a}}{|a|^{2}}=1$$
and therefore we **define** the collection of symbols $$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{|a|^{2}}\bar{a}$$
And this is a bonafide complex number that is an inverse for $a$. Luckily, this satisfies all the usual properties of fractions over $\mathbb{R}$ that I won't talk about in detail.

Finally, we want to show it's unique. But that's not too bad: Suppose $ab=1$ and $ac=1$. Then $ab-ac=a(b-c)=0$. Now multiply by $b$ (or $c$, it doesn't matter), to cancel the $a$, and since $b\cdot 0=0$, we get $b-c=0$. So $b=c$! So there must be only one inverse of $a$. And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You claim you know that $\mathbb C$ is a field with a multiplicative identity, 1, and the property that for every $a \ne 0$ there exists a unique multiplicative inverse, 1/a, such that 1/a*a = 1.

We must prove that by identifying what the value of 1/a $\in \mathbb C$ is, and be showing it is a unique solution to $ab = 1$.

=== old =  skip the first two paragraphs ===

You need to specify that $a \ne 0$.

You can't claim $1/a$ is the value because you do not know that $1/a$ exists and is well defined.  That $1/a$ exists is well-defined and exist is *precisely* what you are being asked to prove.

Basically we know that $1/a$ exist because $\mathbb C$ is a field and that is part of the definition of field.  However we have to prove $\mathbb C$ is a field.  Or in this case just that $\mathbb C$ satisfies the inverse axiom of fields.

==== okay, start reading from here ====

Let's let $a = x + i y \in \mathbb C; a \ne 0$.  If we can solve for $b = w + i z$ such that $ab =1$ and that $b$ is a unique solution, we are done.

$(x + iy)(w + iz) = 1$

$(xw - yz) + i(wy + xz) = 1$

$xw - yz = 1; wy + xz = 0$

$wy = -xz$

Case 1: $x = 0$

Then $y \ne 0$ (as $x + iy \ne 0)

So $wy = 0$. So $w = 0$

$xw -yz = 1$

$-yz = 1$

$z = -1/y$.

There was no ambiguity so $b = (-1/y)i = (x - i y)/(x^2 + y^2)$ is the unique solution to $iy*b = 1; y \ne 0; x = 0$.

Case 2: $y = 0$.  In this case $a = x \in \mathbb R$ and $b = 1/x = (x - i y)/(x^2 + y^2)$ is unique solution.

Case 3: $x \ne 0; y \ne 0$
$xw - yz = 1; wy + xz = 0$

$wy = -xz$

$w = -xz/y$

$-x^2z/y - yz = 1$

$z(x^2/y + y) = -1$

Note: $(x^2/y + y) = 0 \implies x^2 = -y^2$ which is impossible so $(x^2/y + y) \ne 0$.

$z = -1/(x^2/y + y) = -y/(x^2 + y^2)$

$w = -xz/y = x/(x^2 + y^2)$

So $b = (x - y i)/(x^2 + y^2)$ is the unique solution to $(x + y i)*b = 1; x + yi \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$1/a$ is just a notation. To prove the existence of b, write $a=c+id$ and so $b=\frac{c-id}{c^{2}+d^{2}}$ is the inverse of $a$. Indeed $$ab=(c+id)(\frac{c-id}{c^{2}+d^{2}})=\frac{c^{2}+d^{2}}{c^{2}+d^{2}}=1$$
and, similarly, $ba=1$.

If $b_{1}$ is such that $ab_{1}=b_{1}a=1$, then $$b=b1=b(ab_{1})=(ba)b_{1}=1b_{1}=b_{1}$$.

Comment: with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$(a+ib)+(c+id) = a+c+ib+id$$
$$(a+ib)(c+id) = ac - bd + ibc +iad$$
$$(a+ib) \frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2} = 1$$
is obviously a commutative field which contains $\mathbb{R}$ as subfield. what to say more ?

Comment: @user1952009 I did not understand.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me when you said that $1/a$ is just notation! That's what I was stuck on.

Comment: You are welcome.